# forcing emCalc in calc css property

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

Is there anyway to force emCalc to run in Foundation. For example I have this code.

```
.rule {
    height: calc(100% - emCalc(10px));
}
```

The sass simple produces exactly that, without running the emCalc function. Is there anyway to force the sass processor to run the emCalc function first?

Comment: Is the emCalc function enabled?  Sometimes, Foundation has things disabled by default.  If so and it's still not working, you could set it to a variable and use that variable in calc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
.rule {
    height: calc(100% - #{emCalc(10px)});
}
```